# Meaning of Florida statute history abbreviations

Tags: florida, legal-research, statutes, legal-writing

I'm trying to find out how to read the following abbreviations found in the short "history" section at the bottom of a Florida statute website. For example:
"s. 54, ch. 88-1; s. 30, ch. 88-277; s. 36, ch. 91-110"

I would like to follow these references to learn the history of statute, but I'm not sure what they mean or how to follow them.

In case it is helpful, here is [a link](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0700-0799/0760/Sections/0760.23.html) to a statue page with such history information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in [this research guide](http://www.aallnet.org/sections/rips/pdfs/17th-Legal-Research-Teach-In/brownflstatslegislativehistoryresearch.pdf): s.54, ch.88-1 means section 54 of the 1st law passed by the 1988 legistlature, which can be found in the [Laws of Florida](http://laws.flrules.org/). Similarly, s.30, ch.88-277 is section 30 of the 277th law passed by the 1988 legislature.